# Verifying payload when deleting a resource referenced in a JWT

Tags: authentication, token, jwt

I am using a JWT for authentication and in it I put only the user ID from the database. And then on every request I will have access to that payload after verifying the token. This works great!
The problem is when the user is somehow deleted, then the user ID in the token is invalid. But the token itself doesn't know that the user is removed from the database. And I can't force invalidating of the token since it expires in a specific amount of time.

Would doing a database query on every request to see if the user ID is really in the database be OK? I can imagine it wouldn't be a good solution since it can be really slow on many and often received request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, one of the advantages of using JWT tokens is that you can verify their validity without talking to a central server or database.

The downside of this is that it's hard to revoke the token. If you query a database to validate the token, it will hurt the scalability of your system and introduce a single point of failure.

A better approach may be to not revoke tokens and keep the lifetime of the tokens short. If the client has to renew the token like every 15 minutes, the need for revocation may no longer exists.